# Merge arrow in clear case

Tags: clearcase

I have to merge all objects from a sub branch to main branch recursively. I would like to merge manually by check in the code from sub branch to main branch instead of using merge command in clear case.
So after the check in into the main branch I would like to draw arrow
recursively to all my objects.
ic from sub branch to main branch

I have used this command

```
cleartool mkhlink -unidir Merge <sub branch path>>@@/main/<<sub branch>> <<main brach path>>@@/main/LATEST
```

But when I dit it, it is drawing the arrow for the directory only not for all contains of the directory.
Please suggest how to draw the arrow recursively from sub branch to main branch objects.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

According to the [`merge` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm),

```
cleartool merge -ndata -to aFile -version /main/a/SourceVersion /main/a/DestVersion
```

will draw a red arrow without performing any actual merges.

Since you have made your checkout/checkings in a branch or a UCM activity, what you need to do is:

- be in your destination view (the one where the merge occurred)
- query all the versions you made for that merge
- extract the file for each version
- extract the destination version
- compute the source version (for instance /main/aBranch/LATEST)
- do a "`merge -ndata`"

So, it is not so much a "recursive" algorithm, but rather an enumeration of all versions involved in this merge in order to draw the appropriate red arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ClearCase Merge Manager - it should take all the pain out of doing a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 8 months later but have you tried this?

```
cleartool find . -type f -nxname -exec 'cleartool merge -to $CLEARCASE_PN -ndata -version /main/aBranch/LATEST '
```

Probably do not need the `-nxname` in the first part.  I changed to the directory that I wanted to create only merge arrows to and did a FIND for everything in the directory.