# UCM ClearCase error while delivery

Tags: clearcase-ucm

[image: The Error Message]

I have been seeing this error for the past couple of days. I am not able to make any further deliveries because of this.

This happened when I tried to deliver some dlls and exes(binary files) form my stream to the main stream. The delivery failed because ClearCase cannot merge binary files.

I am not able to "Resume the Delivery" or "Cancel the delivery".
The same error crops up all the time.

I tried to look into the Integration view and found the binary files "hijacked". I undid the hijack. But that too did not solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cancel a deliver which is in its complete step.

What you can do is to:

- describe the deliver activity in order to list all  checked out files
- try and check in those files
- resume the deliver

You can get the current deliver activity by going (in a shell) at the root directory of your target view and typing:

```
cleartool lsact -cact
```

Use the result to list all the versions currently delivered:

```
cleartool describe -l activity:deliver.xxxx@\yourPVob
```

Some of those will be in checkout (`grep CHECKEDOUT` to filter them)

Note that for binary file, you can define a special merge type: see "[Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789258/clearcase-ucm-is-trying-to-merge-pdf-files/8789593#8789593)".
Pending that, you might have to make some "red arrow" between source and destination versions of each not-merged binaries, and copy them manually from source to destination.
See "[Merge arrow in clear case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397575/merge-arrow-in-clear-case/2397867#2397867)".