# Find Identical elements in Clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, reportbuilder, cleartool

In ClearCase, Due to different workflow among several developers, we ended up with some files on two branches even though they are identical; this causes unnecessary headache during rebase/merge. To remove those from one of the branch, First, I need to find the list of elements (files/directories) that are identical on BRANCH_1 and BRANCH_2. Is there a way to find this list?

I know how to use Report Builder ( and cleartool scripts) and find difference between two labels, but that does not seem to help here.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, we are talking about the same file,  with two identical versions on different branches.

The easiest way to detect those is through 2 snapshot views (snapshot because quicker for read-access than dynamic views), and by using a simple diff tool (like [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for instance)

For each identical file detected, you can then draw a merge arrow between the two versions from the two different branches. See "[Merge arrow in clear case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397867/6309)".

That merge arrow will be enough for ClearCase to **not consider** (i.e. *ignore*) those same files during the next regular ClearCase merge.

The OP notes that:

> both views have some common files on `branch1` that show up as identical because snapshot has same copy for each view.
>   What I need is just files that exist on different branch but are identical in contents.

Again, the `cleartool descr -fmt` approach is useful: it will allow you to describe an element with their full extended path (with `%n`: `/main/x/branch1/y`): that way, for a file which exists in both views and has been found "identical" by the diff tool, you can check if it is found with 2 different extended pathnames, or with the same one (in which case, you don't have to do anything to that file)

---

Original answer: two identical files on different branches "causing unnecessary headache during rebase/merge" are usually **evil twins**.

The [official IBM documentation about Evil Twin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125072#locate) does advise for a simple [cleartool find](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) (you also have an [old 2010 video on it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt2VLXL83OE)).
Combined with [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), you can launch 2 searches with a `descr -fmt "%En %On\n"`:

- one in aview on `branch1`
- one in a view on `branch2`

That would display the full name of the elements found, along with their oid (object id): 2 files with the same name but different oid would be an evil twin.

You would find a similar approach in "[What's the easiest way to detect “evil twins” in Rational ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705099/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. My situation may not be evil twins. Let's say foo.c exist on \main, then one person creates foo.c on \main\1\branch1, he edits and makes changes to it. Later someone else creates it on branch2 by checking out from branch1, so \main\1\branch1\3\branch2. At this point the branch2 element is checked in and it is different (branch2\1) from 3rd version on branch1 (branch1\3). Later someone checks out branch2\1 and edits it and checks it in creating branch2\2 which becomes identical to branch1\3. How do I find foo.c is identical on branch1 and branch2?

Comment: I just verified by running the commands you suggested, and the file has same OID on both views (one looks at branch1, the other at branch2) so they are not evil by definition. But both files have identical contents, and I need to find all such files on a huge VOB. Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: @user3328803 Ok, I have edited my answer to address your current situation.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but now I realize that it doesn't work the way I expected. Because both views have some common files on branch1 that show up as identical because snapshot has same copy for each view. What I need is just files that exist on different branch but are identical in contents. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3328803 again, the cleartool find -exec "cleartool descr -fmt" approach is useful: it will allow you to list all element with their full extended path (with `%n`: `/main/x/branch1/y`): that way, for a file which exists in both views and has been found "identical" by the diff tool, you can check if it is found with 2 different extended pathnames, or with the same one (in which case, you don't have to do anything to that file).

Comment: @user3328803 I have edited my answer to address your recent comment.